# PostgreSQL - Truncate a table on cascade and reset all hierarchic sequences with 1

Tags: postgresql, sequence, truncate

Is there any way to reset all the sequences of tables, when truncate a table on cascade.

I already read this post [How to reset sequence in postgres and fill id column with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data)

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE t SET idcolumn=nextval('seq');
```

It work only for one sequence, but my problem is to restart all the sequence of the truncated tables.

Consider when I use `TRUNCATE sch.mytable CASCADE;` It affect 3 related tables, which mean three sequences, Is there any solution to restart this sequence in one shot.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `TRUNCATE` statement has an additional option `RESTART IDENTITY` which resets the sequences associated with the table columns.

```
TRUNCATE sch.mytable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
```

If `CASCADE` is defined, then the sequences of all affected tables are reset.